# WebView getting destroyed on its own

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have a fragment ViewPager and inside each fragment is a WebView, defined in the XML.

I'm reading an HTML file from assets into a string (I have to replace something) and then I load the String into WebWiew.
It works and WebView shows the the correct content.

This is my code:

```
webWiew.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                    // show webview when page has fully loaded
                    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });


webWidget.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
String html = Helper.getHtmlAsString(getContext());
if (html != null) {
     html = html.replace(PLACEHOLDER, String.valueOf(pageId));
     webWidget.loadDataWithBaseURL(HTML_WIDGET_PATH, html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

But when scrolling between pages, I get the following error (note that the WebView still displays content):

```
D/webviewglue: nativeDestroy view: 0x1d8b9d0
D/webview: webview.destroy() is called.
D/webview: java.lang.Throwable: webview.destroy() callstack
                                at android.webkit.WebView.destroy(WebView.java:2449)
                                at android.webkit.WebView$10.run(WebView.java:5335)
                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am not destroying the WebView anywhere and I'm definately not calling `webview.destroy()`.

Any suggestions how I can avoid this error?

Comment: You're using a fragment viewpager, maybe the fragment is being destroyed?

Comment: Yes, it probably is, but shouldn't the system take care of cleaning after web view?

Answer (score 0):

Trying putting this code in the onDestroy() method of your fragment

```
protected void onDestroy()
{
yourwebViewPlaceholder.removeView(yourWebView);
yourWebView.removeAllViews();
yourWebView.destroy();
}
```

Let me know if this works for you ! :)

Comment: try removing all views from the fragment in your onDestroy